# Send post parameteres via yii2 Html a()

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to send parameteres via yii\bootstrap\Html;

```
echo Html::a('Создать', ['/orders/order-create','freelancer_group'=>$_GET['freelancer_group']], ['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary','data'=>['method' => 'post','derp'=>'herp'],]);
```

But when I click on it  is still `var_dump($_POST['derp']);` is  `NULL`. How can I post it? I 've found it [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/55562-post-data-params-with-htmla-solved/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo Html::a('Создать',
    ['/orders/order-create', 'freelancer_group' => $_GET['freelancer_group']],
    [
        'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary',
        'data' => [
            'method' => 'post',
            'params' => ['derp' => 'herp'], // <- extra level
        ],
    ]
);
```